# How can we copy between starting point and ending point in a Word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here is the code that I am testing.

```
Sub CopySummary()
    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim lngEnd As Long
    Dim docNew As Document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchCase = False
        .Text = "Start"
        If .Execute = False Then
            MsgBox "'Summary' not found.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        lngStart = Selection.End
        .Text = "End"
        If .Execute = False Then
            MsgBox "'End of Summary' not found.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        lngEnd = Selection.Start
    End With
    ActiveDocument.Range(lngStart, lngEnd).Copy
    Set docNew = Documents.Add
    docNew.Content.Paste
End Sub
```

This basically works, but the problem is that 'Start' and 'End' show up a few times in my document. This code copies only the first occurrence of 'Start' and 'End'.  I want to copy all occurrences of 'Start' and 'End', and all the text in between 'Start' and 'End'. Maybe looping through headings or looping through paragraphs, and doing the search at this level? I don't know much about VBA for Word.

Comment: I suspect you mean  "headings" and not "headers." If so, please edit your question. http://addbalance.com/word/headersheadings.htm If your headings contain what you want, looping through those would definitely be superior. Otherwise, you could mark your text in a special paragraph style, perhaps called 'summary," That would also be easy to pull out

Comment: You are right. I am trying to understand how to loop through headings and copy the text between two specifically named headings.

Comment: The key here is the *paragraph style* applied to the text. You can loop through the Styles collection in the document, testing each instance of a style for the presence of your name. Again, unless there is a separate reason for the name being there, you would be better off using *character styles* to tag your beginning and end.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me.

```
Sub ListPhrases()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim strPhrases As String
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Text = "\Start*\End"
        Do While .Execute
            strPhrases = strPhrases & vbCr & rng.Text
        Loop
    End With
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter strPhrases
End Sub
```